# KnockoutJS - How to exclude an observable from a computed observable

Tags: knockout.js

I have a computed observable that uses ko.toJS() to post values (inner observables) from the view model. One of the inner observables is bound to a textbox. How can I prevent changes to the textbox from automatically triggering the computed observable (i.e. the postback)?

```
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.SearchParams = {
        OrderStatusID: ko.observable(),
        OrderNumber: ko.observable(), // I don't want this observable to trigger the postback
        OrderBy: ko.observable(),
        OrderByDirection: ko.observable(),
        PageIndex: ko.observable(),
        PageSize: ko.observable()
    };

    // This computed observable automatically subscribes to every
    // observable in self.SearchParams. How can I ignore changes to
    // self.SearchParams.OrderNumber?
    ko.computed(function () {
        NS.post({
            url: '/SomeUrl',
            data: ko.toJS(self.SearchParams)
        });
    }).extend({ throttle: 1 });
}
```

Comment: A couple of questions: does OrderNumber need to be sent in the request?  Does it need to be observable (you can bind a non-observable an input and it will write to that property, it just won't notify anyone like your computed)?

Comment: OrderNumber does need to be sent in the request. I assumed it needed to be observable in order to bind it to the input. I can see what happens if it's a non-observable.

Comment: Yes, if your situation is not more complicated (other things depend on `OrderNumber`) then you should be okay.

Comment: That did solve the dependency issue. But I have a reset() function that clears OrderNumber, which now doesn't update the textbox. So, I guess I would still like it to be an observable. Once in a computed, can I check which observables triggered the computed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Knockout 2.2+ includes a `peek` function to access observables without subscribing. So you could do the following:

```
ko.computed(function () {
    var s = self.SearchParams;
    NS.post({
        url: '/SomeUrl',
        data: {
            OrderStatusID: s.OrderStatusID(), 
            OrderNumber: s.OrderNumber.peek(),
            OrderBy: s.OrderBy(),
            OrderByDirection: s.OrderByDirection(),
            PageIndex: s.PageIndex(),
            PageSize: s.PageSize()
        }
    });
}).extend({ throttle: 1 });
```

If you're stuck on Knockout 2.1.0, you can extend observables manually to add `peek` like this (thanks Ryan Niemeyer):

```
var backdoorObservable = function(initialValue) {
    var _value = initialValue,
        result = ko.observable(initialValue);

    result.peek = function() { return _value; };

    result.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        _value = newValue;
    });

    return result;
};
```

And then use `backdoorObservable` for `OrderNumber`:

```
OrderNumber: backdoorObservable()
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this little plugin to help me out in many similar situations:

https://github.com/ZiadJ/knockoutjs-reactor

To ignore certain fields it provides you with the `hide` option which you can use like so:

```
ko.watch(SearchParams, { hide: [SearchParams.OrderNumber] }, function () {
    NS.post({
        url: '/SomeUrl',
        data: ko.toJS(SearchParams)
    });
}).extend({ throttle: 1 });
```